# trying to auto-login at https://kite3.zerodha.com/ using javascript GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, authentication, greasemonkey, autologin

```
document.querySelector('div.su-input-group:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)').value = ('abc');
document.querySelector("#password").value = "abc";
document.querySelector("#dob").value = "abc";

document.querySelector(".button-orange").click();
```

So far this is the code that I was able to write and it does not work on https://kite3.zerodha.com/. The script fails after line number 3. BTW same code works for me on other sites.

Comment: So what's the problem you faced?

Comment: when the third line of code gets executed. password block gets erased

Comment: Are you sure that you need this selector for login on that page?
`document.querySelector("#dob").value = "abc";`

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code is not working on kite3 website is that controls that need to be filled are animated, and they are not available for selection until animation finishes.
Solution for this is usage of waitForKeyElements js library. When these elements become available values can be set, buttons clicked.
Only one criteria is used for wait just to prove the concept.
This code is working for login on that website, just replace username and password with correct values.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Login to Kite
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @match        *kite3.zerodha.com
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements(":password", login);

function login() {
    document.querySelector("[type=text]").value = 'yourUserId';
    document.querySelector("[type=password]").value = 'yourPassword';
    document.querySelector("button").click();
}
```

Comment: You did copy/paste whole script?

Comment: yes. i did copy/paste whole. when the script clicks on the button password field gets erased.